# Goods for resale are considered as producer goods?

Tags: theory

I was looking for the definition of producer goods and this was the first result

> producer goods, also called intermediate goods, in economics, goods
> manufactured and used in further manufacturing, processing, or resale

I understand the further manufacturing and processing part. But what does it mean by resale? Does that mean any good before being sold at a retailer is a producer good?

As you might already tell, I am a beginner. So apologies for asking such basic questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as the definition says, the goods purchased for resale, like carrots purchased by grocer, are intermediate/producer goods.